# How can I search in two tables using union?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to search in two tables using a union query like this:

```
public function searchInAll($keyword) {
    $sql = "(SELECT * FROM user_information 
             WHERE title LIKE ? OR name LIKE ? OR surname LIKE ?)
            UNION
            (SELECT * FROM groups WHERE name LIKE ?)";
    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $result = $query->execute(array("%$keyword%", "%$keyword%", "%$keyword%", "%$keyword%"));
    if($query->rowCount()) {
        $results = $query->fetchAll();
        return $results;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It always returns false. I tried with one table, for example

```
SELECT * FROM groups WHERE name LIKE ?
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM user_information WHERE title LIKE ? OR name LIKE ? OR surname LIKE ?
```

Those work, but for two tables, it does not work.

Why is it returning false?

user_information:
[image: user information table]

groups:
[image: groups table]

**NOTE :**
There is no link between them. They are different tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `SELECT *` and `UNION` if the 2 tables haven't the same number of columns.

You should do instead something like this :

```
(
    SELECT id, name, 'user' AS type 
    FROM user_information 
    WHERE title LIKE ? OR name LIKE ? OR surname LIKE ?
) 
UNION 
(
    SELECT id, name, 'group' AS type
    FROM groups 
    WHERE name LIKE ?
)
```

Comment: but how to use the obtained result in the from of array in php pdo?